# Finding soft links with grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep, symlink

I'm writing a quick program that lists all of the soft/symbolic links in the working directory to a file which is given in argument 1. I'm aware that I need to use grep in order to do so, but in general I have difficulty figuring out how to write the regular expression. In this case, it is especially difficult due to the fact that a variable ($argv[1]) is involved.

The (poorly-written) line of code in question is as follows:

```
ls -l | xargs grep '-> $argv[1]'
```

My intention with this was to catch all of the lines that contained the -> and the specified file, such as

```
link1 -> file
link2 -> file
```

and so on. Is there any way that I can use grep to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry for sounding rude, but why don't you choose `find` for this? `find -L . -samefile name` is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm required to use grep by my professor... otherwise, that would be what I would do.

Comment: I agree with @kworr that `find` is the way to do this. If you must use ls and grep, try `ls -l|grep -e "-> $argv[1]"`. I believe $argv is a csh construct; if you're using bash or ksh, use `$1` instead.

Comment: @AlexIndge Sorry man... This way it looks exactly like another "barometer question". :)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks a lot, this one works!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of language is `$argv[1]`? The (POSIX) Bourne Shell doesn't support arrays. Arguments to scripts and functions are referenced by `$1`, `$2` and so on.
In order for `grep` to not treat the first hyphen in the pattern as an option, use `--` to signal the end of options. Next, there is no parameter substitution in single quotes, only in double qouotes. Putting it all together, this might work:

```
set somename  # Sets $1 to somename
ls -l | xargs grep -- "-> $1"
```

If your grep doesn't understand `--`, try

```
ls -l | xargs grep ".*-> $1"
```

Comment: `$argv[1]` comes from `csh/tcsh`

Comment: I'm writing in C Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Below script can find only the soft / symbolic link files and list only if the argument found on those files,

```
 # cat sygrep.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ $# -eq 0 ]
 then
 echo "No arguments supplied"
 else
 for a in `find . -type l` ; do grep -irl '$1' $a ; done
 fi
```

Output:

```
 # ./sygrep.sh
 No arguments supplied

 # ./sygrep.sh root
 ./mytest.sh
```